# Can't access linux server in local network

Tags: networking, router, ip, routing, home-networking

Problem: Unable to access Linux Mint 20.1 PC from Windows PC after changing new router (TP-Link AX11000)

Router: **TP-Link AX11000**

Machine 1: **Windows 10 PC**

Machine 2: **Linux Mint 20.1 PC**

I was able to winscp / nomachine / ssh from my Windows 10 PC to my Linux Mint 20.1 PC until I changed to new router, and new IP was assign to every device. I am not sure if the problem is due to:

1. ax11000 blocking the connection
2. outdated PC configuration due to new IP
3. Linux Mint 20.1's firewall (I disabled firewall with `sudo ufw disable` and try connecting with the methods mentioned below, and it's don't work. So I don't think firewall is the problem)
4. something else

WinSCP error:

```
Network error: Connection to "192.168.0.231" timed out
```

NoMachine error:

```
A connection timeout has occurred while trying to connect to '192.168.0.231' on port '4000'. The issue could either be caused by a networking problem, by a firewall or NAT blocking incoming traffic or by a wrong server address. Please verify your configuration and try again.
```

- UPnP (Universal Plug and Play) is enabled and port 4000 created by NoMachine is present.

SSH error:

```
# standard ssh to my linux mint don't work as expected
$ ssh -v USERNAME@192.168.0.231
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/USER/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.231 [192.168.0.231] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.0.231 port 22: No route to host
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.231 port 22: No route to host

# ping the IP address to ensure linux mint pc is up (it's because I am looking at the mint pc), from my Windows to my Linux
ping 192.168.0.231
PING 192.168.0.231 (192.168.0.231) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.194 icmp_seq=7 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.194 icmp_seq=10 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.194 icmp_seq=13 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.194 icmp_seq=16 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.194 icmp_seq=19 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.194 icmp_seq=22 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.194 icmp_seq=25 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.0.231 ping statistics ---
25 packets transmitted, 0 received, +7 errors, 100% packet loss, time 24778ms
```

IP info:

```
$ sudo netstat -anutp | grep :22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      64417/sshd: /usr/sb 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      64417/sshd: /usr/sb

$ ip addr
...
    inet 192.168.0.231/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp59s0
...

$ hostname -I
192.168.0.231

$ ip r
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp59s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.231 metric 600
```

How I setup my router: https://www.tp-link.com/us/user-guides/archer-ax11000_v1/chapter-4-set-up-internet-connection#ug-sub-title-1

[AX11000 System Diagnostics](https://www.tp-link.com/us/user-guides/archer-ax11000_v1/chapter-13-manage-the-router#ug-sub-title-8) Output:

```
# Windows 10 PC ping
PING 192.168.0.194 (192.168.0.194): 64 data bytes
Reply from 192.168.0.194: bytes=64 ttl=128 seq=1 time=1.632 ms
Reply from 192.168.0.194: bytes=64 ttl=128 seq=2 time=1.620 ms
Reply from 192.168.0.194: bytes=64 ttl=128 seq=3 time=1.327 ms
Reply from 192.168.0.194: bytes=64 ttl=128 seq=4 time=1.722 ms
--- Ping Statistic "192.168.0.194" ---
Packets: Sent=4, Received=4, Lost=0 (0.00% loss)
Round-trip min/avg/max = 1.327/1.575/1.722 ms
ping is stopped. 

# Windows 10 PC traceroute
traceroute to 192.168.0.194, 5 hops max, 38 byte packets
1 * * *
2 * * *
3 * * *
4 * * *
5 * * *
Trace Complete.
traceroute is stopped. 

# Linux Mint 20.1 PC ping
PING 192.168.0.231 (192.168.0.231): 64 data bytes
Reply from 192.168.0.231: bytes=64 ttl=64 seq=1 time=7.350 ms
Reply from 192.168.0.231: bytes=64 ttl=64 seq=2 time=1.145 ms
Reply from 192.168.0.231: bytes=64 ttl=64 seq=3 time=1.307 ms
Reply from 192.168.0.231: bytes=64 ttl=64 seq=4 time=2.178 ms
--- Ping Statistic "192.168.0.231" ---
Packets: Sent=4, Received=4, Lost=0 (0.00% loss)
Round-trip min/avg/max = 1.145/2.995/7.350 ms
ping is stopped. 

# Linux Mint 20.1 PC traceroute
traceroute to 192.168.0.231, 5 hops max, 38 byte packets
1 192.168.0.231 (192.168.0.231) 35.597 ms 35.319 ms 1.242 ms
Trace Complete.
traceroute is stopped.
```

Any response / pointer / help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does it _really_ show responses from 192.168.0.456?

Comment: @user1686 no, 456 is just a random number I use, to show that it's different from the one I ssh to (123, also random number). But the `192.168.0` prefix is real

Comment: 1. ax blocking connection - no, routers will block WAN<-->LAN ports, 2. what do you mean outdated cofiguration? 3. linux fw - if it worked before the router change it could be cause of an specific allow rule but you disabled it and it does still not work, so no fw issue 4. yes, probably something else, after you changed your router your PCs for sure got diff IP, so go to your linux PC and check with `ifconfig` or `ip addr` and see what IP you have now and then ssh to it from your Windows pc or winscp... also check if your linux is listening properly on 22 `netstat -anutp | grep :22`

Comment: @Zina point 2, outdated configuration refers to linux configuration, I am not 100% if I need to change any config when I change router, I don't think so, but maybe. Point 4, I just included additional IP info, I did run `hostname`, `ip`, `route`, `ip addr` etc to confirm the new IP before I try connecting via WinSCP, NoMachine & SSH. That's why it puzzle me that it don't work.

Comment: what is your Windows IP? Do both PCs have the IP assigned by your router DHCP? Or did you set a static IP on any? the error is on the network side, no route, so it might be that you have set a static IP on one and your new router assigned a IP on the other from a new range, quite often 192.168.1.x/24 is also being used. check your router GUI and see what devices got what IPs.

Comment: @Zina, when I setup my new router, I use `dynamic IP` which is auto-detect, I don't set a static IP, don't know how to do it even if I want. All the devices on my router GUI are within the range `192.168.0.x` which is automatic when I enable DHCP server. Is that going to be a problem since it's not `192.168.1.x` as you mentioned? The TP guide I follow for quick setup: https://www.tp-link.com/us/user-guides/archer-ax11000_v1/chapter-4-set-up-internet-connection#ug-sub-title-1

Comment: no need for the 192.168.1.x - just mentioned it as we do not know how your network is set up. and my question was for your PC IPs. can your PCs ping the gateway (should be your router IP)? can your router ping the PCs? [see here](https://www.tp-link.com/us/user-guides/archer-ax11000_v1/chapter-13-manage-the-router#ug-sub-title-8) - be aware that you might need to stop the Windows firewall too for the ping tests. can your Linux PC ping the Windows PC?

Comment: @Zina, I was able to ping from my PCs to my router, 10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss. As for ping from my router to PCs, I use the AX11000 system diagnostics as you suggested, I pasted the output above. The Traceroute for Linux Mint 20.1 looks interestingly short, is that the problem?

Comment: your windows PC traceroute was an issue if you have the firewall disabled. the linux traceroute 1 line is what we should have seen on the windows PC too. I am glad you resolved it with a router reboot - that would be one of the next steps if all other fail - [have you tried turning it off and on again](https://youtu.be/p85xwZ_OLX0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is embarrassing, but after restarting my router again makes the problem disappear, I swear that I did that and confirm it don't work before I post the question here.

I reach out to TP-Link support to go through the problems with them. Here are some settings to look out for if you are using TP-Link AX11000 and face the same problem

**Advanced > Wireless > Wireless Settings**

- Security: WPA/WPA2-Personal
- Version: WPA-PSK/WPA2-PSK
- Encryption: AES

**Advanced > Wireless > Additional Settings**

- Make sure `AP Isolation` is **disabled**

**Advanced > System > Firmware Upgrade**

- Make sure Firmware is up to date

After ensuring these settings are right, shutdown the router, wait for 5 mins, before starting it again. It should work now, fingers cross.

Also, special thanks to user @Zina for the help.

Comment: it might have been on your Windows PC side, per your output in your question above...